# Read a broken line from text file

Tags: python, file, iterator

if I have a text file like this:

```
[001]This is line 1.
[002][too long]This is line 2 but it's Tooooo
oooo long!
[003]This is line 3.
```

I write a 'for line in fileA' to read this file like:

```
for line in fileA:
    ...
```

now I need to merge the current line and the next line when line.find("[too long]")>=0.
How should I do?

PS:
I wrote:

```
for line in fileA:
    if line.find("[too long]")>=0:
        loc = fileA.tell()
        fileB = open("file.txt") #open this file again
        fileB.seek(loc)
        line += fileB.readline().strip()
```

but it did not work. why?

Comment: you cant open the same file twice, please post the error message / stacktrace, what exactly 'didnt' work? you arent very clear on what you are trying to do, which is hindering our help.

Comment: Iterate through the lines, maintaining a buffer. When a line starts with `[...]`, yield and clear the contents of the buffer, then append the new contents. When a line doesn't start with `[...]`, append it to the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds too much overhead with extra reading of the file. Try this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '[too long]' in line:
            line = line.rstrip('\r\n') + next(f)
        print line
```

prints

```
[001]This is line 1.

[002][too long]This is line 2 but it's Tooooooooo long!

[003]This is line 3.
```

This appends the following line if `[too long]` is found in a line. Maybe you want to append all further lines until a line starts with something like `[xxx]`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension to get all the lines to a list doing something very similar to eumiros answer.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip('\r\n') + next(f) if '[too long]' in line else line for line in f]
```

Then the output is:

```
>>> lines
    ['[001]This is line 1.\n', "[002][too long]This is line 2 but it's Tooooooooo long!\n", '[003]This is line 3.\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the actual file looks like, but I would probably go with something like [this](http://ideone.com/Ng9Mpq):

```
contents = """[001]This is line 1.
[002][too long]This is line 2 but it's Tooooo
oooo long!
[003]This is line 3.
"""

lines = iter( contents.split("\n") )

def fix_file( lines ):
    prev = ''
    number = 1
    for line in lines:
        if not line.startswith( '[{0:03d}]'.format( number ) ):
            prev += line
        else:
            yield prev
            number = number + 1
            prev = line
    yield prev

for line in fix_file( lines ):
    print line
```

This way you do not need extra content in lines.